# Unable to mockk Android ServiceInfo?

Tags: android, mockk

I am trying below to mockk Android API - ServiceInfo class.

```
val resolveInfo = mockk<ResolveInfo>()
 val mockServiceInfo = spyk(ServiceInfo())
 every { resolveInfo.serviceInfo }.returns(mockServiceInfo)
```

This is giving me an exception on the last line:  io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock